# python - object() takes no parameters error

Tags: python, object, parameters, runtime-error

I have following python classes.

```
class FileMaster(db.Entity):
        id = PrimaryKey(int, auto = True)
        description = Required(str)
        filesource = Required(str)
        createdby = Optional(int)
        createddate = Optional(datetime.datetime)
        updatedby = Optional(int)
        updateddate = Optional(datetime.datetime)
        filelists = Set('FileList')

class FileList(db.Entity):
        id = PrimaryKey(int, auto = True)
        filemaster = Required(FileMaster)
        filelocation = Required(str)
        createdby = Optional(int)
        createddate = Optional(datetime.datetime)
        updatedby = Optional(int)
        updateddate = Optional(datetime.datetime)
        transcripts = Set('Transcript')
```

The following line runs fine,

```
filemst = FileMaster(description=desc, filesource = filesourcepath)
```

But the following line gives error "object() takes no parameters"

```
filelist = FileList(filemaster=filemst, filelocation='test')
```

Any one can help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was the issue, but I solved it by removing the tables in the database and used different names for the classess.